# Weighted minimum spanning tree of nbunch of Graph in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I have lists of starting and nodes and the distance between them which I input into networkx as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

s, t = [], [] # int lists assuming long lists of starting and ending nodes forming a meshed network
d = [] # float list of  distance between each starting and ending node
G = nx.Graph()

for i, j, k in zip(s,t,d):
    G.add_edge(s,t, weight=d)
```

c is a list that is a subset of G.nodes(), I want to find the minimum spanning tree of only the c nodes but respecting the weight and topology of the network. Therefore I started by finding the shortest path as follows:

```
for i in range(len(c)):
    for j in range(len(c)):
        for i != j
            path.append(nx.dijkstra_path(G, source=c[i], target=c[j])
```

or:
                path.append(nx.shortest_path(G, source=c[i], target=c[j])

From that I would take the length of the shortest paths to produce a simplified graph between only the c nodes but with the shortest path lengths as the weights between the c nodes and then I find the minimum spanning tree of that simplified graph.

However, when I try dijkstra I get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

When I try, shortest_path I don't get the weights

Any thoughts on finding the weighted shortest path?

Overall is there a better strategy to finding a weighted minimum spanning tree of nbunch nodes in the a Graph?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `networkx.shortest_path_length` has another argument called `weight` that you need to set to `'weight'` in your case such that the weights are considered in the computation (same for `networkx.shortest_path`).

Comment: I would compute the MST first (`networkx.minimum_spanning_tree`) and then compute the new edges.

Comment: Finally, iterate over all unique node pairs with `itertools.combinations(c, 2)` (you are doing twice the work at the moment).

Comment: @Paul why so? Also i am using dijkstra_path() which is supposed to be for weighted graphs but I don't understand the error and using the shortest_path() doesn't consider weight

Comment: Lol, now that you changed your question, you are....

Comment: Didn't change, just added what I previously tried to do which is both dijkstra_path and shortest_path